# Converting images to time series

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, time-series, classification

I'm experimenting using reservoir computing techniques to classify images, but I'm not sure how to convert an arbitrary image to a time series.

I found [this approach](http://izbicki.me/blog/converting-images-into-time-series-for-data-mining) but it doesn't seem to be general enough.

Thanks!

Comment: "how to convert an arbitrary image to a time series": this just doesn't make sense. An image is intrisically 2D. You will find no paper on that topic.

Answer (score 3):

As defined in that article, a time series is just a single-value function of one variable.  However, an image is, in general, a multi-value function of two variables.  So, in order to convert from an image to a 'time series', you're projecting down from a higher dimensional space to a lower dimensional one (for example, the radial scanning technique described collapses the image as a whole into an outline, which reduces the dimension to one).  A key point is that these projections all 'lose data'.  Since they're all lossy, there isn't going to be a 'general' solution that works for all uses of all images.. choosing what data you can afford to lose based on your intended application is a key aspect of using this technique.  So, I guess my answer is that **there is no single general way** to convert an image to a 'time series' that works well for all applications.

Comment: Do you know any paper reviewing different techniques ?

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  Normally what I would do in your situation, since you already have a paper that's on the 'right topic':  look at the papers it references, and then at the papers those reference, and so forth;  back-tracing that reference graph might lead to a paper that fits your needs.  If not, it will at least give you an idea of which authors are writing on the subject, at which point searching those author names can sometimes produce a good paper.  If you're lucky, this process will stumble on a paper that 'surveys the field'.

Answer (score -1):

I would think along those lines.

An image is a static two dimensional array of pixels recorded of a period in time.

A time series is non-static just like a video is a series of images going from one frame to the next in time.

Not sure I answered the question but I hope this helps.